# Failed react-data-grid generation using create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, react-data-grid

I am a novice in today's technologies but am planning to use **react-data-grid** for a pet project.

I am somewhat punch drunk trying to understand `git`, `npm`, `react`, `react-data-grid`, `babel`, `webpack`, `javascript` and, its variants... So I thought I would try generating my first simple **react-data-grid** app with **create-react-app** from Facebook.

I get the following failure during rendering, and I am stuck:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   '**WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react**["React"].createElement')

My simple app.js below is adapted from the template generated from create-react-app.

```
import { React, Component } from 'react';
import { ReactDataGrid } from 'react-data-grid';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this._rows = [];
    this._columns = [];
 }

  getRows () {return this._rows;}

  render() {
    return (
          <ReactDataGrid
            columns={this._columns}
            rowGetter={this.getRows}
            rowsCount={this.state.rows.length}
            minHeight={500} />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I am using:

- react-data-grid 3.0.6
- react 16.2.0
- npm 5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many issues. First the way you import `ReactDataGrid` must be without brackets. Second, in the instantiation of the component you call for `this.state` that is not defined, instead you must call to what you have defined: `this._rows`.
Also I had to install the `create-react-class` package in order to make everything work, probably because it is needed by `react-data-grid`. The `create-react-class` package is needed when some package doesn't use ES6.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDataGrid from 'react-data-grid';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this._rows = [];
    this._columns = [];
  }

  getRows () {
      return this._rows;
  }

  render() {
    return (
          <ReactDataGrid
            columns={this._columns}
            rowGetter={this.getRows}
            rowsCount={this._rows.length}
            minHeight={500} />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```